# Trying to get property of non-object : return multi variable in model codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Controller**

```
    $this->load->model('position_model','m_position');
                $get_supervisor[] = $this->m_position->get_supervisor($id_position);
                $get_position=$this->m_position->get_position($id_position);    
                $data1 = array(
                    'id_position' => $id_position,
                    'name_position' =>$get_position->position_name,
                    'id_supervisorposition'=>$get_supervisor->idsprvisor,
                    'id_supervisorposition1' =>$get_supervisor->idsprvisor1
                    );
                $this->position->ins_employee_position($data1);
```

**Model**

```
 public function get_supervisor($position_id){
$position=$this->get_position($position_id);
$unitid=$position->unitid;
$grade_id = $position->grade_id;
$idsprvisor = $position_id;   //default value;
$idsprvisor1 = $position_id;   //default value;
$get = $this->get_unit_by_unitid($unitid)->result();
$cucok=0;
foreach ($get as $unit) {  
  if ($unit->grade_id<=$grade_id) { 
switch ($cucok){
    case "0":        
      $idsprvisor=$unit->positionid;
      break;
    case "1":        
      $idsprvisor1=$unit->positionid;
      break;
  }
$cucok++;
}
return array('idsprvisor'=>$idsprvisor,'idsprvisor1'=>$idsprvisor1);}
```

Problem in this line

'id_supervisorposition' =>$get_supervisor->idsprvisor,

'id_supervisorposition1' =>$get_supervisor->idsprvisor1

Comment: `$get_supervisor[] = $this->...` this line creates an array, not an object. perhaps you can just remove the square braces: `$get_supervisor = $this->...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning an array from your model function ( `return array('idsprvisor'=>$idsprvisor,'idsprvisor1'=>$idsprvisor1);` ). You cannot access elements in an array  in the same way you access properties in an object.

Check following lines

```
'id_supervisorposition'  => $get_supervisor->idsprvisor,
'id_supervisorposition1' => $get_supervisor->idsprvisor1,
```

if you have `$get_supervisor` assigned to an object you wouldn't be getting this error,but since `$get_supervisor` is actually an array so you cannot access it in this way.

Try this

```
'id_supervisorposition'  => $get_supervisor['idsprvisor'],
'id_supervisorposition1' => $get_supervisor['idsprvisor1'],
```

Comment: Still error 

Undefined index:idsprvisor; 
Undefined index:idsprvisor1;

..

Comment: remove square brackets from `$get_supervisor[]` and comment the result